# How to change chapter image in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, environments, chapters

I'm using a template and all the chapters have the same image in their styling. I want to change it every chapter but I'm not sure how to do it. The template uses tikzpicture and the code is this:

```
% Numbered chapters (with minitoc)
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.north west)
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      % Background image
      \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
           {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{images/back_mat.png}};
      % Chapter heading
      \draw[anchor=west, inner sep=0pt] (1 cm,-1.5 cm) node
           [black,
            ultra thick,
            fill=tsorange!10,
            fill opacity=.6,
            inner sep=10pt]
           (0,0)
           {\parbox[t][1.6cm][t]{\paperwidth}
           {\huge\bfseries\sffamily\flushleft\thechapter. #1}};
      % Chapter Contents
      \draw[anchor=west,inner sep=0pt] (8.8cm,-7cm) node
           [tssteelblue,
            ultra thick,
            fill=white,
            fill opacity=.8,
            draw=tssteelblue,
            draw opacity=1,
            line width=1.5pt,
            rounded corners,
            inner sep=0pt]
           (0,0)
           {\hspace{1cm}\parbox[t][7.1cm][t]{11cm}
           {\vspace{-1cm}\huge\bfseries\sffamily\flushleft
            \textcolor{black}{\sffamily\minitoc}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{7.5cm}
}
```

I wanna change this black image at the background for different chapters, was trying some kind of renew command, but wasn't being able to do it:

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{tstextbook}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sumário}
\tsbook{livro pré vestibular - matemática}
       {Personal Vestibulares - 2020}
       {Cover Designer}
       {2020}
       {xxxxx}{xxx--xx--xxxx--xx--x}{0.0}
       {São Paulo}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Chapters
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\input{chapter1}
\input{chapter2}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Thank's in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Try `\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{images/back_mat_\thechapter.png}`. I cannot test it since you do not provide a complete minimal document, but this should load `back_mat_1.png` for chapter 1, `back_mat_2.png` for chapter 2, etc

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track.

In the class `tstextbook.cls` the background figure for a chapter is fixed.  In order to change it according to the chapter number, you need to do two things:

(1) Add the code to change the command used by the class `\@makechapterhead` as shown in the code, where the original line  `{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background}};` was changed to
`{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{back-chap-\thechapter}};` so now the image used will depend on the chapter number.

Or edit the `tstextbook.cls` file yourself and change that single line.

(2) Provide the background images, name them `back-chap-1`, `back-chap-2` (while keeping the file format) and so on, and put them in a directory named `background-images` in your working directory.

I chose three images (example-image-a, example-image-b and example-image-c)  from the `mwe` package and renamed as explained in (2).

[image: aaa]

This is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{tstextbook}

\makeatletter
% Numbered chapters (with minitoc)
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.north west)
    {
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        % Background image
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
%        {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background}};
        {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{./background-images/back-chap-\thechapter}}; %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed
        % Chapter heading
        \draw[anchor=west, inner sep=0pt] (-0.1cm,-1.5cm) node
        [black,
        ultra thick,
        fill=tsorange!10,
        fill opacity=.6,
        inner sep=10pt]
        (0,0)
        {\parbox[t][1.6cm][t]{\paperwidth}
            {\huge\bfseries\sffamily\flushleft\thechapter. #1}};
        % Chapter contents
        \draw[anchor=west,inner sep=0pt] (8.8cm,-7cm) node
        [tssteelblue,
        ultra thick,
        fill=white,
        fill opacity=.8,
        draw=tssteelblue,
        draw opacity=1,
        line width=1.5pt,
        rounded corners,
        inner sep=0pt]
        (0,0)
        {\hspace{1cm}\parbox[t][7.1cm][t]{11cm}
            {\vspace{-1cm}\huge\bfseries\sffamily\flushleft
                \textcolor{black}{\sffamily\minitoc}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{7.5cm}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{One}
    \chapter{Two}
    \chapter{Three}
    
\end{document}
```